# Jmeter REST multipart POST with file

Tags: json, jmeter, multipart

I've been trying to figure out how to post a json http request.
Haven't found any SO topics that explicitly answered the question, so am reposting it in a different form

I've set the HTTP Header Manager with `Accept: application/json ; Content-Type: Application/json; Content-Dispositions: attachment`

I've set the raw body data to

```
{ "post":   {"title":"Hello", "file": "${myfile.pdf}" } }
```

I've also add a file to the list, with parameter name myfile.pdf and mime-type : application/pdf

When I inspect the request generated using JMeter proxy, all I seem to be getting in the Request is the pdf file, and no JSON request...

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather select POST in the HTTP request method and simply paste the below in HTTP request parameter value without providing parameter name

```
{"title":"Hello", "file": "${myfile.pdf}" }
```

Comment: "post" in the example is the name of the entity, like a "blog post"